# Long Boot Time (SSD), black screen with blinking cursor, "gave up waiting on suspend/resume device"

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, disk

Have a Debian-based Linux that has been hardware cloned a few times.  There are long boot delays even though it has an SSD.

Originally, there had been a little slowly spinning icon saying it was waiting for a job before it timed out.  For this, I found a swap file referenced in /etc/fstab that didn't actually exist so I deleted it's line with the corresponding UUID and that "job/timeout" error went away...

...but got replaced with a long blank screen with blinking cursor that flashes a message before it displays the login prompt.  The message it flashes is:

```
Gave up waiting on suspend/resume device.
/dev/sda1 [some disk metrics here]
```

/dev/sda1 is the only partition that exists according to gparted.  I'm trying to clear up this long boot delay and find the cause of what it's waiting on.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT:  I tried re-creating a swap file based off of this answer:  https://superuser.com/questions/1204627/deleted-a-partition-now-getting-gave-up-waiting-for-suspend-resume-device-mes/1204634 but the same delay occurred but the error message changed to some problem with journaling -- it's too quick for me to see. -- So I just deleted the SWAP file and commented out it's reference in /etc/fstab that brought me back to the problem above.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `lsblk` and `cat /proc/swaps` and your `/etc/fstab`. Do I understand correctly that the current state is that you no longer have a spinning icon, but you get delays at boot? What can you see *before* the delay? Does `dmesg` contain anything relevant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Happens after deleting the `swap` partition

If a `swap` partition is deleted (e.g. on purpose when migrating from HD to SSD), the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` should be either completely empty or read `RESUME=`. Delete any `UUID` number. `RESUME=NONE` is not valid.

```
$ sudo gvim /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

The [initial RAM filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk) requires updating for these changes to take effect:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: doing this results in an attempt to auto-detect resume device

Comment: I just change the UUID with current swap's UUID