# Long boot time of Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, suspend, fsck

My Debian Stretch system takes nearly a minute to boot up. It usually takes about 15 seconds.

My error:

```
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext4 for /dev/sda1
fsck exited with status code 8
```

Note: I migrated my physical Debian box to Virtualbox. I did not have these error on the physical machine and it booted very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

After much googling, I got the answer that fixed this frustrating error. It has to do with removing the swap partition. I had a swap partition on the physical machine, but I do not on the virtualized instance.

Here are the steps that successfully fixed my problem:

- Remove swap entry from `/proc/swaps`
- Execute `sudo swapoff -a`
- Remove swap entry from `/etc/fstab`
- Execute `sudo systemctl mask dev-sda.swap` (Replace `dev-sdX.swap` with your correct device)
- Remove swap entry from `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` (I emptied this file, but didn't delete it.)
- Execute `sudo update-initramfs -u`
- Reboot

Sources:

- https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/09/msg00866.html
- https://serverfault.com/questions/684771/best-way-to-disable-swap-in-linux

Now I'm booting as fast as I should be!

Comment: Found another helpful answer just now... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368322/long-boot-time-ssd-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor-gave-up-waiting-on-sus